# Is this a CSS box shadow? On the left AND right?

Tags: css, shadow

I am so sorry for asking this question here because I'm pretty sure it's not 100% what this forum is for (although it is CSS I presume) but I asked on another forum and no one understood what I was talking about!! So I thought: I'm 100% sure someone here will know!

What is the website box shadow (I think it's a CSS box shadow?) that they use on websites like this one:

http://www.rcgp.org.uk/

-the box shadow I mean is to the left and right of what I assume would be the body container and it helps give the page a general frame - of note the shadow slowly fades and disappears completely by the end of the 'Find Courses & Events' box.

Thank you in advance and I appreciate your wisdom!

Comment: yes it looks like box-shadow

Comment: It's a background image: http://www.rcgp.org.uk/images/main-bg.jpg - Use the web inspector of your browser to see quickly.

Comment: i didnt look at the source. i think you can achieve something similar with box shadow. but might be harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page uses a fixed width container (940px, `#wrapper`) for all content. The shadow is simply an image which has just the correct dimensions:

```
body{
    /* ... */
    url("../images/main-bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you all. I have never used the web inspector but I will from now on. Thanks again everyone!